# Deployment specific volumes in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible to create a volume that is shared between all pods in a deployment but impossible to mount for any other pod?

Alternatively that is read/write from one deployment and just read from any other pod?

Answer (score 1):

That could be addressed in [Kubernetes 1.12](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/09/27/kubernetes-1.12-kubelet-tls-bootstrap-and-azure-virtual-machine-scale-sets-vmss-move-to-general-availability/#additional-notable-feature-updates) (Q3 2018) with **Topology aware dynamic provisioning**, which is now in beta.
That means storage resources can now understand where they live.
This also includes beta support to AWS EBS and GCE PD.

See [kubernetes/feature 561](https://github.com/kubernetes/features/issues/561) and its [doc PR 9939](https://github.com/kubernetes/website/pull/9939) ([commit e1e6555](https://github.com/kubernetes/website/commit/e1e655507d91f2eeb882bef6d5091b7f434f867c))

See [Storage / Storage Classes / Volume Binding Mode](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#volume-binding-mode) (beta in K8s 1.12)

> By default, the `Immediate` mode indicates that volume binding and dynamic provisioning occurs once the `PersistentVolumeClaim` is created. 
>   For storage backends that are topology-constrained and not globally accessible from all Nodes in the cluster, `PersistentVolumes` will be bound or provisioned without knowledge of the Pod’s scheduling requirements. This may result in unschedulable Pods.

[Allowed Topologies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#allowed-topologies) is how to restrict the topology of provisioned volumes to specific zones.

```
allowedTopologies:
- matchLabelExpressions:
  - key: failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone
    values:
    - us-central1-a
    - us-central1-b
```